# Mfc CComboBoxEx - How to change the background color

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a class that is derived from CComboBoxEx and I'm trying to change the background color. I was thinking that it would work like a ComboBox (using the SetBkColor function), but it doesn't change the background color.

Here's what I have tried :

```
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyComboBoxEx, CComboBoxEx)   
       ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

     void CMyComboBoxEx::SetBkColor(COLORREF backgroundColor)
         {
            m_backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            m_brBkgnd.DeleteObject();
            m_brBkgnd.CreateSolidBrush(backgroundColor);
         }    
     HBRUSH CMyComboBoxEx::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
         {
            HBRUSH brush = __super::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
            pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255,0,0));

            return brush;
         }
```

I've tried with `OnEraseBkgnd()` too and it didn't worked either.

Do I need to subclass a derived CComboBox class and set the background color in that class?

Thx.

Comment: Do you have a `WM_CTL_COLOR()` entry in your message map?

Comment: The `WM_CTLCOLOR` message is sent to the parent dialog box; but I think it isn't sent for the 'list box' part of a combo. What I have done to achieve this is to declare the combo as 'owner drawn' and then handle that.

Comment: @sergiol Yes, I'll edit my question, Thx :)

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Ok, so you are handling the DrawItem() function ?

Comment: The inner combobox is returned by `CComboBoxEx::GetComboBoxCtrl`

Comment: May be you need to implement your own class of inner combobox and after do the `SubclassWindow`

Comment: Yes, I already have my own derived class of combobox, I'll try that !

Comment: Emile - Yes, I add the `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style in the resource script and handle draw the combo *via* the `OnDrawItem()` member of the containing dog-box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that all the answers you've got so far suggest either handling `WM_CTLCOLOR` in parent window or use one of `OWNERDRAW` styles.

Handling `WM_CTLCOLOR` in parent window means you'll need to duplicate that code in each parent window's class where you'll use such combobox. This is obviously a bad solution if you want to use combobox more than once.

Adding `OWNERDRAW` style may have impact on other existing controls that you'd like to subclass and you may need to handle additional problems. That's also far from a sinmple solution.

Fortunately, there's another way to solve it - use [Message Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn062-message-reflection-for-windows-controls?view=vs-2019). And all you need to do is to add `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()` entry to the message map and `CtlColor` handler.

In case of combobox control I'd do it like this:

*MyComboBoxEx.h*

```
class CMyComboBoxEx : public CComboBoxEx
{
public:
    CMyComboBoxEx();
    virtual ~CMyComboBoxEx();

protected:

    CBrush m_BkBrush;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor);
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
};
```

*MyComboBoxEx.cpp*

```
CMyComboBoxEx::CMyComboBoxEx()
{
    m_BkBrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)); 
}

CMyComboBoxEx::~CMyComboBoxEx()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyComboBoxEx, CComboBoxEx)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH CMyComboBoxEx::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    return m_BkBrush;
}

HBRUSH CMyComboBoxEx::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    return CtlColor(pDC, nCtlColor);
}
```

Here's how such combobox looks:

[image]

If you want to have custom color for borders and glyph then you need to handle WM_PAINT yourself.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, this seems to be the best solution, but when I try it, it doesn't work for some reason. My control is a CMyComboBoxEx and I've done the exact same thing as your code example. Am I missing something ? :S

Comment: @Emile I added working example (but haven't changed anything in `CtlColor` logic)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `WM_CTLCOLOR` messages are sent to the *parent* window (dialog box, probably) of your combo control, not to the control itself; also, in the case of the drop-down 'list-box' part of the combo, this message is not sent (as the dialog doesn't need to draw it unless the control has been activated).

The way I have achieved what you want is by making the control owner-draw and then (manually) drawing each item in the list.

First, you need to add the `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style to your control in the `.rc`/`.rc2` script; like this, for a typical combo:

```
COMBOBOX  IDC_IGONG, 224, 68, 52,120,
    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

Then, you need to add `ON_WM_DRAWITEM()` to the message map for your dialog class, and override its `OnDrawItem()` member. Note that the message is sent once for *each item* in the drop-down list, when the list is made visible by user-action:

```cpp
void MyDialog::OnDrawItem(int nIDCtl, DRAWITEMSTRUCT *pDIS)
{
    switch (pDIS->CtlType) { // You can switch on the ID if it's only one combo!
    case ODT_COMBOBOX:
        DrawDropDownBox(this, nIDCtl, pDIS);
        break;
    default:
        CDialogEx::OnDrawItem(nIDCtl, pDIS);
        break;
    }
}
```

The `DrawDropDownBox()` does all the hard work:

```cpp
void MyDialog::DrawDropDownBox(CWnd *box, int nID, DRAWITEMSTRUCT *pDIS)
{
    CComboBox *pCBC = dynamic_cast<CMyComboBoxEx *>(box->GetDlgItem(nID));
    if (pCBC == nullptr) return; // Skip if we can't get handle to the control
    CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pDIS->hDC);
    wchar_t buffer[4096]; // Or just char if you ain't using Unicode
    if (pCBC->GetLBText(int(pDIS->itemID), buffer) == CB_ERR) return; // Maybe called during WM_DELETEITEM
    int dcSave = pDC->SaveDC(); // Save DC state for later restoration
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 0, ListColor); // ListColor is COLORREF for your desired b/g
    if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_DISABLED) {
        pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_PEN);
        pDC->SelectObject(BackBrush); // A CBrush for disabled: defined/created elsewhere
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    }
    else {
        pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
        pDC->SelectObject(ListBrush); // A CBrush that draws your desired b/g
        pDC->SetBkMode(OPAQUE);
    }
    CRect rc(pDIS->rcItem); pDC->Rectangle(&rc); // This draws the b/g
    if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_DISABLED) {
        pDC->SetTextColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_GRAYTEXT));
    }
    else if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) { // Use Windows defaults if selected...
        pDC->SetTextColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
        pDC->SetBkColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
    }
    else {
        pDC->SetTextColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
        pDC->SetBkColor(ListColor); // Custom b/g color
    }
    unsigned format = DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER; // You desired text alignment
    pDC->DrawText(CString(buffer), rc, format);
    pDC->RestoreDC(dcSave); // Restore DC's saved state...
    pDC->Detach();          // ...then 'release it'
    return;
}
```

The code shown handles both disabled combos and selected items in the list; you could possibly skip some of these, if you want to simplify the operation.

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: I can't code inside the dialog, can I do the same thing inside my class ?

Comment: @Emile Probably! You'll still have to add the `CBD_OWNERDRAWFIXED` or `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` style in the resource script (or somewhere), and provide your own `void CMyComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS)` class member. You should be able to use the `pDIS` in much the same way as the code I've shown; and the `pCBC` then just equates to `this` for your class object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all about just changing Bk color of the control, then you have to handle `WM_CTLCOLOR` message in control's parent window:

```cpp
HBRUSH CMyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_MY_CONTROL)
    {
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 0)); //Black color
        hbr = m_hbrBlack;              //Black brush.
    }

    return hbr;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to draw your control totally yourself in your derived class, with `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` or `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` style, which is way more complicated, but ofc possible.

Comment: I can't do it in the parent's dialog because I don't want to copy the code everytime I use a ComboBoxEx :/