# Setting specific CComboBoxEx (Extended combobox) items to bold with text colour

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

I have a `CComboBoxEx` that displays some images and talk numbers:

[image: Combo]

How can the text of specific combo items properties?

- Set font to **bold**.
- Set font colour.

I know that for `CComboBox` I can make it owner draw and create the font and render the combo item myself. But this is `CComboBoxEx` and it is catering for images so owner draw would be harder.

Is there a simple solution to set specific `CComboBoxEx` items as bold and with a specific text colour? Thanks.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755028/mfc-ccomboboxex-how-to-change-the-background-color) and I thought I might be able to do it that way but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Your only chance is to make it owner-drawn.

Comment: How do I draw the icon and text? I know about drawing just the text strings alone, but with icons?

Comment: CComboBoxEx has item icons, but not bold feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class?view=vs-2019 ... it is suitable for you ?

Comment: @flaviu2 I am already using that class. My question states that.  But thanks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed :)

Comment: As Nick said, the only way is to customize yourself by owner-draw. But you will lose the OS theme. You can read this article: http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/02/22/custom-draw-vs-owner-draw-controls/

Comment: I saw in romanian forum this (is helpfull): For a CBS_SORT style combobox or listbox owner-draw, respectively LBS_SORT sends the message WM_COMPAREITEM that allows the owner to sort the items. In the MFC, the CompareItem virtual function can be overwritten in the control class. (Taken from here: http://www.codexpert.ro/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=1880)

Comment: Thanks @flaviu2. At the moment I have changed my GUI design to use the regular combo with coloured/bold text and I now have a MFC Button with icon on the dialog that changes based on the state of the combo.